# includes every template along with its CSS in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to make every template along with its CSS like Angular or Vue Js so I have done some tries and it's work well here is my shote:

```
<head>
    <style>
      {% include "style.css" %}
      {% block style-custom %}{% endblock %}
    </style>
</head>
```

and for every template:

```
{% block style-custom %} 
/* some styles */
{% endblock style-custom %}
```

the problem with this way I haven't the ability to change my style like in real CSS it's like a text so I'm asking if there is another way to write my own style inside style tag, like that I will have the ability to change my own styles as I want.

for example, is better if I can to write my styles inside style tag like

```
<style>
/* some styles */
</style>
```

Comment: i didn't get a word of your problem!!! please edit your question with a better explanation

Comment: Have you ever work with angular or VueJs? @EbrahimKarimi

Comment: no, but i do it with react js

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would like this to work?

Comment: https://github.com/Noah-Lc/PNMS/blob/master/src/Components/Dashboard.vue

Comment: the link above has the example, has the HTML code and also CSS code inside style tag like <style>/* some styles */</style>

Comment: Your question is "how can I use a <style> tag instead of a {% block %} tag in my templates"?

Comment: @IainShelvington yes exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a static file like `main.css` and include it in your base html. Then for every template that inherits from the base.html, you can add css for that specific template in your main.css file. Hope it works!

Comment: Thanks but I have a lot of pages so I will have a lot of css files